# Access all ongoing ASP.NET Session States

Tags: asp.net, signalr, session-state

What we have is an ASP.NET web app that also does some signalR notifications. Since SignalR cannot access ASP.NET session states we need some other way to validate they are a client logged in on the web app.

In most situations you would think a static dictionary would help. As long as one of the ASP.NET Controllers made sure to keep a cache of key client info (via IP/browser info, or some generated token the client send up to signalR later) -- as long as this was done, then SignalR could validate the client connection before adding it to its pool.

*However* we are working in a server-farm situation, with SessionState backed by SQL. What this means is that a given server instance, even if it had a static cache of all its clients, may not *know* about Client C. Of course if Client C made a normal web request, it would *find out* about Client C when it fetched the SessionState. So the question is, IF work is handed over to a second server instance (Machine B) at just the right/wrong time, where Machine B does not know about client C (except via a context-dependent SessionState fetch, inaccessible from SignalR), HOW could we validate the client on the SignalR side?

All it would require is for some static means of getting ALL clients, OR, simply a "static" context for SessionState (i.e. a server-Session State). Because either way, we could sift through the individual client SessionStates and validate "yes, this client had a session state on a previous machine".

Is there any other way than for the client to reload the page, so that ASP.NEt can "cache up" its info locally? That is the only way I see so far.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a perfect scenario for "SignalR Backplane", it's designed for a webfarm situation to Scaleout SignalR. Lots of articles available, please search.